# Require override keyword when implementing a function

Tags: scala, lint

I want to keep the codebase clean by always using `override` in front of an overriding method implementation, but it seems to optional in Scala. Is there a tool, plugin, or parameters to check the code style conforms to using `override`?

Comment: Looking back, I see I didn't really answer your question. However, personally _prefer_ to leave it off. It's not only more concise, but allows the compiler to help me catch conflicting changes in base classes. That makes me wonder if there's a way to check that I'm *not* using override :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scala compiler requires an `override` keyword for all members that *actually* override a concrete member in a base class. It is forbidden if no base class has that member.

So, short answer: Yes, there is a tool, and it's the Scala compiler.

Note that the `override` modifer is optional when implementing abstract methods. This is a good design decision, as it allows you to retroactively mix in traits. If you accidentally mix in a trait with a conflicting concrete definition, the compiler warns you by telling you that you have a missing `override` modifier.